# AsyncTask or service or thread for storing into data base

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service, android-asynctask

Say, I got 10k data that needs storing in the database ( I'm estimating this will take bout a minute at most ) but this data is not needed for the UI.

What's the best way to store this? Using asyncTask? Service? Or threads?

And if I were to use asyncTask / threads will they still stay "active" for a minute even if the activity is closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `JobIntentService` might be the choice. It's not activity-related, will not be destroyed with an activity.

How to use:

1. Manifest,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<service android:name=".YourService" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
```

2. Create the service:

```
public class YourService extends JobIntentService {

    public static final int JOB_ID = 1;

    public static void enqueueWork(Context context, Intent work) {
        enqueueWork(context, YourService.class, JOB_ID, work);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleWork(@NonNull Intent intent) {
        // Your jobs are here
    }

}
```

3. Start the job somewhere:
   `YourService.enqueueWork(context, new Intent());`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Another question, would the JobIntentService still run even if the application is killed? Since the data must be stored even if the activity is stopped or even if the app is killed. Or would Service be better suited for that? or neither?

Comment: @JiwaChhetri, yes, the JobIntentService will be killed within a few minutes of the APP being killed. Your job needs a minute, time looks enough.